# How to override default route metric (1024) for dhcp client interface with systemd-networkd config?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing, systemd-networkd, metric

systemd 237 in Ubuntu 18.04 sets route metric for defaultroute received via DHCP on wired interface to 1024. However, defaultroute on NetworkManager's controlled wlan interface is set to 20.

Is there any way to override default metric on DHCP client size with systemd wired interface config if I want to prefer default route via wired interface if both interfaces are up? I know, I could do so with NetworkManager, but with systemd-networkd?